# How to get the length of an object after checking it is an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, there is one field in each object could be boolean or a string of array, for instance

```
myObjects=[{id: "fruit", selected: true}, {id: "veggie", selected: ["tomato", "cucumber", "potato"]}, {id: "diary", selected:[]}]
```

I would like to filter out the objects that have selected either not empty or true. The result would be:

```
result=[{id: "fruit", selected: true}, {id: "veggie", selected: ["tomato", "cucumber", "potato"]}]
```

Here is my code:

```
for (const object in myObjects) {
if (!object[selected] || (Array.isArray(object[selected] && object[selected].length ===0)) continue
...
}
```

But objects with selected is empty array won't get filter out. I got a typescript error

```
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'boolean | string[]'.
  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'false'.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You use a for...in loop on an array of objects? Should this not be for...of loop?

Comment: You could use a `.filter()` function. Something like `myObjects.filter(obj => (typeof obj.selected === 'boolean' && obj.selected) || obj.selected.length > 0)` to filter out any boolean false or empty arrays

Comment: There is a bad condition grouping, must be `if (!object[selected] || Array.isArray(object[selected]) && object[selected].length === 0) continue`

Comment: From what I tested, this should be a SyntaxError (in the `if` there's 3 opening parentheses and only 2 closing). So maybe there's something missing from the code posted here, compared to what you actually ran. It could be because instead of "continue;", you used a function or something else that is acceptable inside `if` (edit: I think it would only work with an operator actually). If you could clarify that, it'll probably be helpful. But yeah, what @n-- said matches with the behaviour you presented, it looks like the `length` part is inside the `isArray` function.

Comment: If you're going to use bracket notation, you need to use `object["selected"]` otherwise it's looking for a variable called `selected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the filter method on the myObjects array

```
const res = myObjects.filter((object) => object.selected.length > 0 || object.selected === true )
```

Comment: The specific error he's seeing is because of typescript, so something like: `myObjects.filter(obj =>  Array.isArray(obj.selected) ? obj.selected.length > 0 : obj.selected === true)` is required

Comment: Agreed, was just pointing out that this answer doesn't solve the issue `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'boolean | string[]'.`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with loop [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

add object to `result` array only if `selected` property is `boolean and true`:

```
(typeof object.selected === "boolean" && object.selected)
```

or `selected` property is `an array and have elements`:

```
(Array.isArray(object["selected"]) && object["selected"].length !== 0)
```

```js
const myObjects = [{
    id: "fruit",
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    id: "veggie",
    selected: ["tomato", "cucumber", "potato"],
  },
  {
    id: "diary",
    selected: [],
  },
];
let result = [];
//                vv replace 'in' with 'of' since you loop over an array not an object
for (const object of myObjects) {
  if (
    (typeof object.selected === "boolean" && object.selected) ||
    (Array.isArray(object["selected"]) && object["selected"].length !== 0)
  )
    result.push(object);
}
console.log(result);
```